# duration of statuses in percent per day

Tags: php, algorithm, date

I need help with algorithm.
In general I have array like this:

```
**Status** (3 options available), **Start** (in timestamp format), **Duration** (in seconds)
**Status**, **Start**, **Duration**
**Status**, **Start**, **Duration**
and so on.........
```

Duration may be from few minutes to couple of days. I wish to calculate somehow, how much percent of day each status consumed.

```
date1 | %of status1 | %of status2 | %of status3
date2 | %of status1 | %of status2 | %of status3
```

final output needed

```
2014-09-08 | 73 | 22 | 5
2014-09-07 | 100 | 0 | 0
2014-09-06 | 46 | 34 | 20
```

I don't have any code to show, because i can not figure out algorithm, how this could be achieved. Any help would be appreciated

My input is CSV file and I will program this in PHP, but help in any language would be appreciated.

Comment: group lines per "date", get their duration, determine the percentage of  secondPerDay? But dates/time offset, etc. can be tricky. What is the "Start" is 23:59:55 and duration is 10 seconds. Does that need to be split over days? Is every combination of a day counting up to it's 100%? lots of info missing before a decent answer can be provided

Comment: Yes, situation like 23:59:55 and duration 10 seconds are possible. I've tried to provide as much as possible information, that would help to solve my problem. If anything more is required- I'll try to provide even more.

Comment: In that case you will have to build a "usage per day" for each status type in some form of list/array. Given the expected "required calculation", you cannot just use the info you have. It needs processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone interested- i've managed to create algorithm

```
<?php
//prepare my $csv array as in question

$final = array();
foreach($csv as $key => $val){

    //start + duration, is still the same day?
    if (date('Y-m-d', $csv[$key]["start"]) == date('Y-m-d', $csv[$key]["start"]+$csv[$key]["duration"])) {
        $final[date('Y-m-d', $csv[$key]["start"])][$csv[$key]["status"]] += $csv[$key]["duration"];
    }
    //we have to split duration of status over days
    else{
        //timestamp of upcomming midnight
        $midnight = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $csv[$key]["start"]), date('d', $csv[$key]["start"])+1);
        $tillMidnightDuration = $midnight - $csv[$key]["start"];
        $afterMidnightDuration = $csv[$key]["duration"]- $tillMidnightDuration;

        $final[date('Y-m-d', $csv[$key]["start"])][$csv[$key]["status"]] += $tillMidnightDuration;

        $day=0;
        //handle after midnight duration
        while($afterMidnightDuration>0){
            //after midnight- next day
            $day++;
            // 86400 is one full day in seconds
            if($afterMidnightDuration > $secondsPerDay){
                $final[date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $csv[$key]["start"]), date('d', $csv[$key]["start"])+$day))][$csv[$key]["status"]] += $secondsPerDay;
                $afterMidnightDuration = $afterMidnightDuration - $secondsPerDay;
            }
            // not full day
            else{
                $final[date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $csv[$key]["start"]), date('d', $csv[$key]["start"])+$day))][$csv[$key]["status"]] += $afterMidnightDuration;
                $afterMidnightDuration = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now in $final array i have day as key and duration in seconds for each status